# FOR iterator block in Simulink and model's input

Tags: matlab, for-loop, input, simulation, simulink

Hello I'm building a exe from a simulink model and in order to do that I pass the inputs to it through a .mat file.

[image]

My question is, since in my model is present a "for each" block, how can I store the data in the .mat file?  Normally (without the for each block) I would store the input as a constant vector in the workspace (see the upper part of the simulink model) and it will handle automatically how to pass the data during the simulation time. But in my case, since I want to export as .exe and pass the input programmatically, I need the input as .mat file and the presence of the "for each" block screw up the building the vector time (since is unclear how to combine time vector with data vector inside the .mat file because is unclear to simulink which data take at a given simulation time.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Please create a simple model, showing specifically how you are trying to set up your blocks, and upload an image of the model.  From your description it is difficult to know exactly what you are having trouble doing.

Comment: Hello @PhilGoddard, I've just edited the post with the simplified picture of my model. In the upper part is what I have (that works). In the bottom part I have the model that I have to build (substantially I replaced the constant input by the From File .mat) since I want to export the .slx to .exe in order to optimize the computation time and the inputs are manageable easier through .mat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what the specific problem you are having is.

In your upper diagram, the model will run when you have a variable

```
>> input = 1:3;
```

If you turn on `Display->Signals & Ports->Signal Dimensions` then you'll see that the signal coming out of the `Constant` block has a dimension of `3`.

For the lower diagram, create a variable in MATLAB, that since it will be used in a `From File` block, must adhere to the specifications required for that block, which means the first row is a time vector, so

```
>> t = [0 10]
t =
     0    10
>> u = [1 1;2 2;3 3]
u =
     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
>> tu = [t;u]
tu =
     0    10
     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
```

And then save this variable to your file,

```
>> save input tu
```

Now the signal coming out of the `From File` block will also be of dimension `3`.

Change the values of `t` and `u` to suit your specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm also considering to compile it with rapid simulation target. There is any way to specify the Sample time after I get the .exe file? Because it is possible to modify the inputs and parameters but for the Sample time I am not sure.

Comment: You can't change the sample time of the model after compiling.  You can change the `t` of the data that you're feeding in through the mat file.

Comment: But if I have problem with an integrator (e.g. step size not sufficiently tight) I would not solve the problem simply by defining a `t` with a shorter step size because the sample time defined before compiling the model into the exe will not affect anything, right?

Comment: The model sample time, defined in the model and compiled with it, cannot be changed.  There are many consequences of doing that, including, if your data changes and effects the performance of an integrator, then you cannot change it.